# Is there a first order theory for equivalences classes?

Tags: logic, category-theory, model-theory

Question will be a bit naive, so please, be kind.

Consider a first order theory, $\Gamma$ . Let $\mathcal{M}$ be the category of models for $\Gamma$. Consider $\sim$ an equivalence relation on $\mathcal{M}$.

Is $\cal M/{\sim}$, in any sense, the category of models of any first order theory?

Comment: Considering that the collection of models is a proper class, $\cal M/{\sim}$ is [generally] a $2$-class, it's a class whose elements are classes. Perhaps you want to consider some $\cal M'\subseteq M$ which includes exactly one model from each equivalence class.

Comment: I knew someone would have observed it, question is clearly not well posed. I do believe you've catched my idea. Suggest any working formalization.

Comment: Well, thinking about it a bit more, it's not quite clear that my previous comment is what you *really* meant. We can consider the equivalence classes as some sort of a structure of some language (although it's unclear what is the language, and it might depend on the relation itself).

Comment: "We can consider the equivalence classes as some sort of a structure of some language".

This is my aim but  I do not know how to move in this direction.

Comment: What are the morphisms under consideration? What do you mean by an "equivalence relation"? A category is not just a collection of objects.

Comment: I don't know what is gonna work, may I try with quotient maps or a selection of maps for equivalence relation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{M}$ be the category of Kan complexes. (The morphisms are the morphisms of simplicial sets.) Kan complexes are models for a many-sorted first-order theory. Let $\sim$ be the relation of simplicial homotopy. It is well known that $\mathcal{M} / {\sim}$  is equivalent to the homotopy category of CW-complexes, and a theorem of Freyd shows $\mathcal{M} / {\sim}$ does *not* admit a faithful functor to $\mathbf{Set}$. In particular, it cannot be the category of models for any first-order theory.

Comment: Any link to theorem?

Comment: See [here](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/6/tr6abs.html).

Comment: You cannot get how grateful I am.